# DisplayActionSheet keeps appearing even though i'm choosing an item xamarin.forms UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

i have a DisplayActionSheet that appears on Entry Focus. the thing is that after it appears and i choose an item, the DisplayActionSheet doesn't disappear it keeps popping up and i choose again and again and it keeps popping up. i don't understand why because it works well on both android and ios, but on UWP, it seems to be different. here is the code:

```
 async private void edlevel_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            urlClass urldata = new urlClass();
            string uri = urldata.url + "/GetAllEdlevels/4";
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responsepost = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (responsepost.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    string outcome = await responsepost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<edlevels>>(outcome);

                    string[] edlevels_lst = new string[result.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                    {
                        edlevels_lst[i] = result[i].edlevel;
                    }

                    string action = await DisplayActionSheet("Education Levels", "OK", null, edlevels_lst);
                    if (action == "OK")
                    {

                        edlevel.Text = "";
                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edlevel.Text = action;
                        
                    }
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(edlevel.Text))
                    { 
                    if (edlevel.Text.Trim() == "Kgs" || edlevel.Text.Trim() == "Nursery")
                    {
                        discount.IsToggled = false;
                        discount.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        discount.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                }

                }


                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Operation Failed", "Response Failed!", "Cancel");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException exp)
            {

                bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Please Check Your Internet Connection!", "Retry", "Cancel");
                if (ans == true)
                    edlevel_Focused(sender, e);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Lost Connection!", "Retry", "Cancel");
                if (ans == true)
                    edlevel_Focused(sender, e);
            }

        }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If it only happens on `UWP` then there might not be a solution. I've run into numerous problems with `Xamarin Forms` and `UWP` and what's wrong with `UWP` but there are loads of issues at current. So I made a decision to only develop for `Android` & `iOS`.

Comment: ooh, that's upsetting :( ...thanks for replying

Comment: Can the user type in the Entry?  Why not use a button or label instead?

Comment: when i use a label, the DisplayActionSheet  doesn't appear at all, as if the focused event doesn't happen

Comment: A Label can’t have Focus, but you can add a TapGesture to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use the label with adding a `TapGesture`. When you click the label twice you will triger the Tapped method.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="tap GestureRecognizers">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
 </StackLayout>
```

In the cs file:

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
           urlClass urldata = new urlClass();
            string uri = urldata.url + "/GetAllEdlevels/4";
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responsepost = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (responsepost.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    string outcome = await responsepost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<edlevels>>(outcome);

                    string[] edlevels_lst = new string[result.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                    {
                        edlevels_lst[i] = result[i].edlevel;
                    }

                    string action = await DisplayActionSheet("Education Levels", "OK", null, edlevels_lst);
                    if (action == "OK")
                    {

                        edlevel.Text = "";
                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        edlevel.Text = action;
                        
                    }
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(edlevel.Text))
                    { 
                    if (edlevel.Text.Trim() == "Kgs" || edlevel.Text.Trim() == "Nursery")
                    {
                        discount.IsToggled = false;
                        discount.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        discount.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                }

                }


                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Operation Failed", "Response Failed!", "Cancel");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException exp)
            {

                bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Please Check Your Internet Connection!", "Retry", "Cancel");
                if (ans == true)
                    edlevel_Focused(sender, e);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Lost Connection!", "Retry", "Cancel");
                if (ans == true)
                    edlevel_Focused(sender, e);
            }
        }
```